# How to create a table in postgreSQL without execute DDL script

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating an application where the user can create tables in database (by using an assistant).

Sometimes I get a deadlock because I can't modify database structure while sessions are active (AccessExclusiveLock).

I'm trying to find a way to create a table without executing DDL script.
( or to figure out my current problem )

Comment: You cant. "You cant  make an omelet without breaking some eggs"

Comment: Can I safetly delete "idle" connections ? I'm having troubles with "procpid" and "pid" because the solution of kill sessions will be incorporated in application and I can't create separate codes for different postgres versions. Damn, why do this guys such thing? Stop changing names...

Comment: What error message are you getting, and what SQL statements are causing it? An exclusive lock shouldn't be a problem if you're *creating* a table.

Comment: There should not be idle (in transaction) sessions. If there are, that is a bug in your application. As for the `procpid` to `pid` change, yes, I really wish that hadn't been done; it's prettier, sure, but it's a horrible backward compat choice.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' It could be if the table creates foreign key constraints that reference other tables that're locked by an uncommitted ALTER TABLE or other exclusive locking statement.

Comment: @MagnoC You need to be more specific. How do you have these active uncommitted sessions in the first place? Why don't you commit your transactions immediately after doing work? What specific errors are you getting, from running what statements? On what PostgreSQL versions? (BTW: How would creating a table without "executing DDL script" possibly work? It'd have to just be another way of doing the same thing, and it'd have to take the same locks anyway.)

Comment: @CraigRinger: I didn't think of that. But the whole situation smells like an XY problem.

Comment: Thanks all. It's strange because all my logs ( in all DAO ) tells me all sessions are correctly commmited and closed. I think I need to trace deeply Hybernate behaviour. I agree I have a problem with some opened session. @Craig Ringer I was very specific with my error: I got a deadlock because a `CREATE TABLE` when active sessions is in place and need for some professional advices ( "close your sessions correctly" is a good advice, I know ). I think Hibernate is causing this somehow. I'll investigate and post results here soon. Tell more will be speculation.

Comment: By the way, the `pg_stat_activity` table structure is all messed up. Please PostgreSQL guys, STOP doing this... Changing names will not agregate anything. Why `name` type in `datname` attribute? What is the problem with `text` or `char`?

Comment: @MagnoC Because `name` is an internal data type with a specific meaning. It is exposed to SQL because it is not the same as `text` or `varchar`. (No not use `char`). It's a 63-character fixed-width string. It's been like that since ... forever ... and nobody wants to change it to avoid breaking backward compat ;-) like you complained of above. Plus Pg would have to support preserving typmods (like `char(63)`) in transient values before it could be done.

Comment: Finally I found my bottleneck. After removed I got no more deadlocks. Thanks all.